# Failed to create kubernetes cluster using Rancher

Tags: rancher

I am trying to use Rancher to create Kubernetes cluster in VMWare vSphere.

Rancher : Using docker to install
Installation option (Docker install/Helm Chart): Docker Install

When I tried to create cluster, I faced this error:

```
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "rancher.cattle.io.secrets": failed to call webhook: Post "https://rancher-webhook.cattle-system.svc:443/v1/webhook/mutation/secrets?timeout=15s": no endpoints available for service "rancher-webhook"
```

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when I create namespace:

```
# kubectl create namespace minio-operator
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "rancher.cattle.io.namespaces.create-non-kubesystem": failed to call webhook: Post "https://rancher-webhook.cattle-system.svc:443/v1/webhook/validation/namespaces?timeout=10s": no endpoints available for service "rancher-webhook"
```

This works for me:

```
# kubectl delete validatingwebhookconfigurations rancher.cattle.io
# kubectl delete pod -n cattle-system -l app=rancher-webhook
# kubectl delete secret -n cattle-system cattle-webhook-tls
# kubectl create namespace minio-operator
namespace/minio-operator created
```